# project a list using a combining function

Tags: r

say I have this vector with 5 points:

```
> x <- c(2,4,6,8,10)
```

and I want to compute a 4-element vector comprising the midpoints of the elements in `x`

```
> xmid <- numeric()
> for (i in 1:(length(x)-1)) {xmid[i] <- (x[i] + x[i+1])/2}
```

but more generally, I just want to be able to project a list/vector/table/whatever with `n` elements into one with `n-1` elements by applying a combining function `combineFunc` to the `ith` and `(i+1)th` elements:

```
> xmid <- some_cool_combining_function(x, combineFunc)
```

I'm having a difficult time finding a way to do this without the for-loop.  Any suggestions?

Comment: not understanding the downvotes... how could I make this question better?

Comment: One thing you could improve is the title. Perhaps make it more relevant for those searching for help with a similar problem.

Comment: `f <- function(x) sapply(2:length(x),function(i)median(x[(i-1):i]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for midpoint specifically I might do

```
diff(x)/2 + x[-length(x)]
```

But for the more general case, something like

```
apply(embed(x,2), 1, mean)
```

would be useful. The `embed(,2)` function will reshape your data such that pair-wise elements will each have their own row in the matrix. Then you can just use the `apply` function to run whatever function you like for each of the pairs in each of the rows.

Comment: `embed` is clever... I don't know if I would have ever run into it on my own.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 for `embed` -- the coolness factor more than makes up for the 30x slowdown compared to `diff`!

Comment: @josilber Yes, it's not as efficient by far. I wish base R had better rolling-window style functions.

Comment: I've never tried it, but how does `zoo::rollapply` perform?

Comment: @MrFlick it's too bad the some of the coolest functions, e.g. `rle`, often yield the slowest solutions to common processing problems.

Comment: Of course this particular example could be sped up by rowMeans(). Also, for a fast run-length encoding, see S4Vectors::Rle from Bioconductor.

Comment: Good points @MichaelLawrence. `rowMeans`/`colSums` are the right way to work with matrices, and only use `apply` when you have to, but it should always work.